# beautiful soup automatically converting string to time format?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, timezone, utc

I'm trying to scrape a div which has 'time' information from a website (using beautifulsoup + selenium):

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, 
chrome_options=options)

#Set base url (San Francisco)
base_url = 'https://www.bandsintown.com/?place_id=ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo&page='


events = []
eventContainerBucket = []

for i in range(1,35):
    #cycle through pages in range
    driver.get(base_url + str(i))
    pageURL = base_url + str(i)
    print(pageURL)

    # get events links
    event_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=_3buUBPWBhUz9KBQqgXm-gf] a[class^=_3UX9sLQPbNUbfbaigy35li]')
    # collect href attribute of events in even_list
    events.extend(list(event.get_attribute("href") for event in event_list))


# iterate through all events and open them.
item = {}
allEvents = []
for event in events:

      soup = bs(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class^=Y_sOCKLIZzxDZWauPTJlk]').get_attribute('outerHTML'))
      soup2 = bs(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class^=_2j34xcqD4slSOyTCMbA1dY]').get_attribute('outerHTML'))


        # Get time
        time = soup.select_one('img + div + div').text
        print(time)
```

This keeps converting time to UTC when I don't want it to.  I just want to pull the raw text for each time, i.e. 9:00 PM.  I've tried parsing the raw string right away, so it just grabs the string:

```
time = soup.select_one('img + div + div').text
' '.join(time.split(' ')[0:2])
#time.replace('UTC','')

print(time)
```

But it's still printing out with UTC, i.e. 2:00 AM UTC.

Is there a way to pull just the raw string, before it's automatically converted to a time?  I don't want to deal with time zones, and I don't think I need to for this project.  Just want raw string.

Comment: see edits to question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using Beautiful Soup `select`. Can you just get the text of the element using Selenium?

```
for event in events:
    # using locator from your example below, although it did not work for me
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class^=Y_sOCKLIZzxDZWauPTJlk]')

    # Get time
    time = element.text
    print(time)
```

Output:

```
6:00 PM PDT
```

Not sure this is what you are looking for, but hopefully this is helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Odd, tried your solution and still printing in UTC timezone for me.

Comment: Could my script somehow be inferring UTC timezone as my timezone?